# Amazon EC2 to AWS Elasticache Redis connection problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache, redisson

I am connecting to AWS Elasticache Redis via Redisson from my Amazon EC2 instance. After lots of request of redis connection, I get the following issue which halt my program execution. The problem doesn't  occur for few request to redis interation, but it eventually happen after lots of requests.

```
2018-10-11 11:02:38,363 ERROR org.redisson.client.handler.CommandsQueue - Exception occured. Channel: [id: 0x46c06a6a, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:49308 ! R:redis-pa-qc-001.redis-pa-qc.yzmnbg.use1.cache.amazonaws.com/10.0.24.226:6379]
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1412)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:943)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:141)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1429)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:813)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:292)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1248)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1159)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1194)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.(PKIXValidator.java:90)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:179)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:312)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:171)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:239)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1493)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:919)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:916)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1369)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1408)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1316)
... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.(PKIXParameters.java:120)
at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.(PKIXValidator.java:88)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is basically `JVM` is not able to get the required `SSL certificates` to establish the connection. Check your Java version and update it.

And update the java ca-certs.

Run:
`sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java"` (Ubuntu system) or

`update-ca-certificates -f`